# How is Vue automatically adding properties to my q-input within a custom component I created?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm using Vue 3.2.4, Vuex 4.0.1 and Quasar 3.1.0 for this project.

I have created a custom component in vue as shown below:

```
<template>
  <q-input outlined v-model="inputValue" :label="label" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'RobsInput',
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    }
  },
  emits: ['input'],
  data: function () {
    return {
      inputValue: (this.value
        ? this.value
        : ''),
      open: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$emit('input', this.inputValue);
  },
})
</script>
```

I was then adding it to a page with some validation needed and pre-emptively added a `rules` property before actually adding this to my component, as shown here:

```
<robs-input
      v-model="email"
      label="Email Address"
      lazy-rules
      :rules="[ val => val && val.length > 0 || 'Email Address is Required']" />
```

What's really strange is that the `lazy-rules` and `rules` properties instantly began applying to the q-input inside my `robs-input` without me making any changes to the custom component itself.

Is Vue automatically adding properties to q-input because it's the only element within my component? Seems strange for it to do that, but I can't figure out what else is happening.

Thanks in advance for any answers to this.

Comment: If you have one root element in your child component, and you add attributes to It at your parent component, then It gets passed directly to your first element, which in this case is a q-input.

Comment: all non-props attributes are inherited by the root element of your component unless u use inheritAttrs: false in your component options, more on this https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs

Comment: Thanks so much! Could you reply as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called non-prop attribute inheritance (doc here: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html). The important sections are:

> When a component returns a single root node, non-prop attributes will automatically be added to the root node's attributes

and

> If you do not want a component to automatically inherit attributes, you can set inheritAttrs: false in the component's options.

and for multiple roots component:

> Unlike single root node components, components with multiple root nodes do not have an automatic attribute fallthrough behavior.